# Use columns of a data frame as arguments for a function using pmap

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr, pmap

I'm trying to compute a function whose arguments are names of a column in a data frame. I need to loop over each row and compute the function.  It seems pmap is a neat way to do this, but I'm forced to specify the " ..1, ..2, " notation to indicate column positions in the data frame.  That's not a very reproducible way of running this I think.

Although, it just knows the names of the columns when I use an anonymous function, instead of a named one.

```r
library(purrr)
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
toy_df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = 3:12) 
toy_function <- function(a, b, c) {
  data.frame(result = a^2 + b^3 + log(a)*c + sin(a)*b)
}

## this fails  
toy_fail <- purrr::pmap(toy_df, ~ toy_function())
#> Error in data.frame(result = a^2 + b^3 + log(a) * c + sin(a) * b): argument "a" is missing, with no default

## this works  
toy_pass <- purrr::pmap(toy_df, ~ toy_function(..1, ..2, ..3))


## this works and I didn't need to specify the positions  
toy_also_pass <- purrr::pmap(toy_df, function(a, b, c){
  data.frame(result = a^2 + b^3 + log(a)*c + sin(a)*b)
})
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```r
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, c(list(f = toy_function), toy_df)))
#        result
# 1    10.68294
# 2    36.50048
# 3    79.05754
# 4   145.53375
# 5   246.51252
# 6   391.37817
# 7   583.76908
# 8   822.69864
# 9  1109.29066
# 10 1452.64679
```

In tidyverse, the equivalent would be

```r
purrr::invoke(purrr::pmap_dfr, list(.f = toy_function, .l = toy_df))
```

but it allows for a much simpler

```r
purrr::pmap_dfr(toy_df, toy_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we don't need the anonymous function call as the column names are the same as the arguments to the function and it matches

```
purrr::pmap(toy_df, toy_function)
```

---

Or another option is

```
purrr::pmap(toy_df, ~  do.call(toy_function, as.list(c(...))))
```

---

Or using `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
toy_df %>%
     rowwise %>%
     transmute(result = toy_function(a, b, c))
```

Comment: Oh dang that's interesting - thank you! Do we need a tilde only when we specify .x, .y in a map2 ? Is there ever a need for it in pmap?

Comment: *"is there a need"*? it's a lot for convenience, when the names and/or positions don't match up perfectly. When that's the case, in "traditional R", one would write `function(...) { ... }`, a verbosely-written anonymous function. `rlang` allows for a more terse description using the tilde format (though it only works here because `pmap` "knows" about rlang's tilde-funcs).